# Mocha with nodejs

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to run some Mocha tests within my Node.js app.

Here is my folder structure:

```
compute/
  folder1/
    app/
      tests/
        mytest.js
  folder2/
    app/
      tests/
        mytest2.js
```

I got a `package.json` in both with mocha installed.

When I try to start a test with `yarn test`, I got an error

> Warning: Could not find any test files matching pattern: test
>
> No test files found

How can I manage to run it?

Because my folders' names are "tests" and not "test" as in the default and they are not at source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't use the default folders, you need to specify them as arguments. An example follows:

```
mocha "folder{1,2}/**/tests/*.js"
```

If you want to run with only `npm test`/`yarn test`, then you need to update your `package.json` file like following:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha \"folder{1,2}/**/tests/*.js\"",
  },
```

Comment: Ok and if I change the folder name by "test", mocha will run all my tests into subdirectories ?

Comment: I updated my folders to "test" and in package.json got "test" : "mocha" but it is still not working

Comment: can you update your question with the related lines from package.json.

Comment: Oh ok I got it, it works, I did bad with the link when I tried to run the command "mocha folder1/..."